# How to mock third party component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I need to mock a third party component in Jasmine, as one of it's lifecycle method throwing error while running tests. So, I think there might be some way of mocking a third party component method, I know how to mock services using useClass but unable to find something similar for mocking a component.

```
    Ngondestroy(){
this.removeCol()
}
```

Comment: can you give an example code . Its as simple as overriding the variable with another same variable name.

Comment: I am using primeng library and one of components ngondestroy method is throwing the error

Comment: @skeptor I am unable to find the code for mocking the component, could you please help

Comment: Give some code, which fails .

Comment: @skeptor I have updated the post

Comment: The above code gives the error that calling method of undefined

Comment: @skeptor could you provide the mocking code